# Unwanted blank page at front of document

Tags: pdftex, margins, geometry, blank-page, changepage

I'm currently writing my thesis and I want my document to have 1 inch margins for the main body of the text so I've used the `geometry` package to do this. However I want the title page to have a 2 inch margin so for this I used the `changepage` package and it's basically done what I need except that, for some reason, there is a blank page before my title page whenever I generate it.

Below is the simplest version of my scipt that still gives me the same error (extra blank page).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1in}{1in}
\title{\textbf{[Title]}}
\author{[My name]}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
[My abstract]
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
[Some text stating my supervisor and course.]
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the blank page will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! From my point of view the problem is `\maketitle` inside of `adjustwidth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the `\maketitle` to have smaller margins, you can use `geometry`'s `\newgeometry`/`\restoregeometry`. Something like this works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
\title{\textbf{[Title]}}
\author{[My name]}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{hmargin=2in}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{center}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

But it might make more sense to just use `adjustwidth` after `\maketitle` instead.